# Spotfire Calculation using previous rows calculated data

Tags: for-loop, spotfire

I have been struggling with the following calculation. I have tried a few previous, next and  overs but I cant seem to get the syntax correct.

Basically i need to subtract demand from stock on hand, to get a new column. the the next row will use the newly created column as stock on hand and the subtract the demand for that row, then that result becomes the new stock on hand etc. i cant get it to loop. I have ranked the demand in order of date required per plant. AS the data set will have multiple Plants, SOH and demand.
The attached pic shows A020 only has one QTY short so that is straight forward, but for A030 opening SOH is 152, and the 1st date QTY short is 12, so i need 152-12 = 140. then the second date QTY which is ranked 2, needs to be 140 - 12 = 128, so then rank 3 uses 128 - 12 and so on. ie the SOH needs to dynamically update.
[data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyLpc.png)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be natively possible in point-and-click Spotfire (happy to be corrected if this is incorrect).

You should consider writing a data function using R to do this groupby-loop operation.